# How do I write this pbtxt using python?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

How can generate `label_map.pbtxt` using python?
I need to generate `label_map.pbtxt` file automatically by sending object name.

```
item {
  id: 1
  name: 'object name'
}
```

I tried to create that using python functionality but when I start to train a model I get this error:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'!

Answer (score 3):

```
def label_map_v1(objname):
with open('/TEST-DS-TO-RECORD/annotations/label_map.pbtxt', 'a') as the_file:
    the_file.write('item\n')
    the_file.write('{\n')
    the_file.write('id :{}'.format(int(1)))
    the_file.write('\n')
    the_file.write("name :'{0}'".format(str(objname)))
    the_file.write('\n')
    the_file.write('}\n')
```

This can generate file that I need.

Answer (score 3):

```
from google.protobuf import text_format
with open("obj.pb.txt", "w") as fw:
    text_format.PrintMessage(obj, fw)

with open("obj.pb.txt", "r") as fr:
    text_format.Parse(fr.read(), obj)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @DonaldDuck this answer is perfect. Audience such as myself is wondering if an API exists to take arbitrary protobuf message and dump to txt. Yes it does -- the 'text_format' thing above. Excellent.